Help identify black, brown bugs in Virginia
Please help identify these black, brown bugs found in the bathroom in a home in Virginia.  The bathroom has mold due to a pipe that was leaking.
They are very small and maybe 1 mm in length.  The stuff surrounding the bugs is human hair.  Notice the long antenna on the bug on the left that is as long as the body.
I thought they might be springtails but I do not see furculas, and the tail on the left bug looks strange, where it seems there are hairs or parts sticking out in a circular fashion.
U.jpg
